# Android Studio android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, firebase

I've an error called: 
"android.view.InflateException".

That happens when i'm trying to open a specific activity, and for some unknown reason- it happens only to specific devices (yes devices, not users).
Another clue is that when it happens - the specific activity crashes.

- I cannot show you the error given in the Android Studio's logcat simply because I have only one device that I regularly use USB debugging with, and on that device - it works perfectly. While, with the exact same code - it doesn't work (cannot open that very specific activity) on most of my users devices (20) and on some specific others (2 so far) - works perfectly.
- Another intersting thing is that when I comment all the code i've put inside this activity's java file (inculdes the variables declaration, so as of the views on the xml file) - it still crashes.

I've been searching online and trying everything for over than 3 weeks... and i'm very very frustrated....

Any ideas how to solve this?

This is a crash report I managed to get from Android Vitals, under the title:
"android.view.InflateException".

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2416)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2476)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1344)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:742)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:632)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:139)
  at com.pullup.pullapp.pullapp.Chats.PrivateChatActivity.onCreate (PrivateChatActivity.java:82)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6251)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1107)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2369)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:645)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:764)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:835)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Native Method)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$ChildDrawable.<init> (LayerDrawable.java:1723)
  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$LayerState.<init> (LayerDrawable.java:1792)
  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.<init> (RippleDrawable.java:998)
  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState (RippleDrawable.java:989)
  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState (RippleDrawable.java:988)
  at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.mutate (LayerDrawable.java:1652)
  at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.mutate (RippleDrawable.java:975)
  at android.view.View.applyBackgroundTint (View.java:17419)
  at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable (View.java:17295)
  at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.access$001 (FloatingActionButton.java:69)
  at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$ShadowDelegateImpl.setBackgroundDrawable (FloatingActionButton.java:862)
  at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonLollipop.setBackgroundDrawable (FloatingActionButtonLollipop.java:73)
  at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init> (FloatingActionButton.java:188)
  at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init> (FloatingActionButton.java:158)
```

Comment: It looks like you are targeting api level >=21 and some views are failing to inflate because they can't make use of new functions.

Comment: @MoGa so how can I fix this?

Comment: In your code, check for any red highlights and hover over them. They should give you a tip that this may not work on old devices. In that case you should apply one of the suggestions like `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {}`

Comment: @MoGa IT WORKED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you so so much !!!! :)

Comment: Im glad to hear that, I will post the answer, please accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it turned out to be API level issue. Some functions can not work on API level less than 21.

Simple check for the version could solve it

```
(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { ... }
```